# How to draw a flow graph like this

Tags: d3.js, graph, charts, highcharts, gis

[image]

I have the geodetic coordinates of the stations, and the data flowing into the station is generated randomly. Is there any graph libary can draw this?

Comment: I don't know what the random data exactly is, but  I am sure both (d3js)[https://d3js.org/] and (leafletjs)[http://leafletjs.com/] can display positions on a map.

Comment: @1Cr18Ni9 Just to show there is data flowing into the station. It's kind of like bus line graph,  the start point can be anywhere, but its end point must be one of the stations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the map you can use [d3-geo](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#geographies-d3-geo) and the `d3.geoAlbersUsa` projection.

To draw the line into the stations you can use a SVG path. You can generate the path with [d3.geoPath](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md#geoPath).